# Issue with selection drop box

Tags: jquery

There are three select menu boxes, it will trigger an error message if any of the menu boxes is not selected. The user have to select the menu in sequence order:

```
"Please Select Port" > "Pls Select Grade" > "Pls Select Months"
```

When user selected the first menu box, then the second menu box will be activate and available to select the menu, so on and so forth. After click on submit will display the chart.

https://jsfiddle.net/yingchor/wo2z79pm/1/

Comment: We ask that questions are self-contained here, so please copy the essence of your Fiddle into your question. Please do not work around editor restrictions in this fashion in the future - they are there for a reason. We are keen that if an external link breaks (as they often do) the question is not rendered meaningless.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @j08691 After select the port how i can enable to select for the grade using jquery?

Comment: After try here is my results https://jsfiddle.net/yingchor/wo2z79pm/4/